# apply diff() function in a csv file and then export to another csv file

Tags: r, csv

I am able to read out each column dataset from each individual cvs file and then use diff() function to calculate the difference in each time step. After done that, I can write to another csv file.

I am looking forward more advanced way to do this task. Any good ideas?

My dataset:

```
    timestamp   c1.1    c1.2    c1.3    c1.4    c1.5    c1.6    c1.7    c1.8    c1.9    c1.10   c1.11   c1.12
1   2015-08-13 18:30:00 1970.75 1973.81 1965.77 1953.62 2035.94 1959.28 1985.22 1962.63 1955.05 1952.25 2010.46 1996.06
2   2015-08-13 21:30:00 1968.87 1972.71 1963.52 1952.29 2035.03 1958.61 1984.38 1960.87 1953.44 1951.83 2008.73 1994.43
3   2015-08-14 00:30:00 1969.74 1972.39 1964.06 1952.44 2035.59 1958.40 1983.44 1961.65 1953.45 1951.61 2009.37 1994.27
4   2015-08-14 03:30:00 1970.31 1972.57 1963.91 1952.33 2035.62 1958.41 1983.63 1961.71 1953.21 1951.67 2009.35 1994.42
5   2015-08-14 06:30:00 1970.75 1971.79 1964.28 1952.28 2035.66 1958.26 1983.39 1961.54 1953.40 1951.70 2009.40 1994.05
```

Here is my procedure:

```
fpath_ch1 = file.path("ch1_1h.csv"); 
data_ch1 = fread(fpath_ch1, header = T, sep = ','); 

diff_ch1_c1.1 = diff(data_ch1$c1.1);
diff_ch1_c1.2 = diff(data_ch1$c1.2);
diff_ch1_c1.3 = diff(data_ch1$c1.3);
diff_ch1_c1.4 = diff(data_ch1$c1.4);
diff_ch1_c1.5 = diff(data_ch1$c1.5);
diff_ch1_c1.6 = diff(data_ch1$c1.6);
diff_ch1_c1.7 = diff(data_ch1$c1.7);
diff_ch1_c1.8 = diff(data_ch1$c1.8);
diff_ch1_c1.9 = diff(data_ch1$c1.9);
diff_ch1_c1.10 = diff(data_ch1$c1.10);
diff_ch1_c1.11 = diff(data_ch1$c1.11);
diff_ch1_c1.12 = diff(data_ch1$c1.12);

QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.1 = ifelse(diff_ch1_c1.1 <= -5 | diff_ch1_c1.1 >= 5, NA, diff_ch1_c1.1);
QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.2 = ifelse(diff_ch1_c1.2 <= -5 | diff_ch1_c1.2 >= 5, NA, diff_ch1_c1.2);
QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.3 = ifelse(diff_ch1_c1.3 <= -5 | diff_ch1_c1.3 >= 5, NA, diff_ch1_c1.3);
QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.4 = ifelse(diff_ch1_c1.4 <= -5 | diff_ch1_c1.4 >= 5, NA, diff_ch1_c1.4);
QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.5 = ifelse(diff_ch1_c1.5 <= -5 | diff_ch1_c1.5 >= 5, NA, diff_ch1_c1.5);
QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.6 = ifelse(diff_ch1_c1.6 <= -5 | diff_ch1_c1.6 >= 5, NA, diff_ch1_c1.6);
QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.7 = ifelse(diff_ch1_c1.7 <= -5 | diff_ch1_c1.7 >= 5, NA, diff_ch1_c1.7);
QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.8 = ifelse(diff_ch1_c1.8 <= -5 | diff_ch1_c1.8 >= 5, NA, diff_ch1_c1.8);
QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.9 = ifelse(diff_ch1_c1.9 <= -5 | diff_ch1_c1.9 >= 5, NA, diff_ch1_c1.9);
QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.10 = ifelse(diff_ch1_c1.10 <= -5 | diff_ch1_c1.10 >= 5, NA, diff_ch1_c1.10);
QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.11 = ifelse(diff_ch1_c1.11 <= -5 | diff_ch1_c1.11 >= 5, NA, diff_ch1_c1.11);
QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.12 = ifelse(diff_ch1_c1.12 <= -5 | diff_ch1_c1.12 >= 5, NA, diff_ch1_c1.12);

dfrm <- data.frame(timestamp = data_ch1$timestamp(2:length(data_ch1$timestamp)), c1.1 = QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.1, c1.2 = QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.2, c1.3 = QAQC_diff_ch1_c1.3)

write.table(dfrm, file="z_st.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=T)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the columns except the first one i.e. 'timestamp' (`lapply(data_chi[-1], ..`), get the `diff`, and based on the logical condition, we replace the elements with `NA` using `ifelse`, and finally `cbind` with the first column of the dataset.

```
library(data.table)
setDF(data_chi)#convert to `data.frame`.
dfrm <- cbind(data_chi[-1,1],data.frame(lapply(data_ch1[-1], function(x) {
             x1 <- diff(x)
             ifelse(x1 <=-5|x1 >=5, NA, x1)})))
```

#### Update

Just noticed that the data was read with `fread`.  In that case, it would be a `data.table`.  Therefore, we can try the `data.table` syntax.  We specify the columns to loop in `.SDcols` and loop those columns with `lapply` (`lapply(.SD, ..`), get the difference (`diff`), replace the `diff` values that are less than or equal to -5  or greater than or equal to 5 as `NA`, create a column 'timestamp' without the first row from the original column 'data_chi$timestamp'

```
DT <- data_chi[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {x1 <- diff(x)
            NA^(x1 <= -5 | x1 >=5)*x1}), .SDcols= 2:ncol(data_chi)
           ][, timestamp := data_chi[[1]][-1]]

 DT[, c(ncol(DT), 1:(ncol(DT)-1)), with=FALSE]
 #         timestamp  c1.1  c1.2  c1.3  c1.4  c1.5  c1.6  c1.7  c1.8  c1.9 c1.10 c1.11 c1.12
#1: 2015-08-13 21:30:00 -1.88 -1.10 -2.25 -1.33 -0.91 -0.67 -0.84 -1.76 -1.61 -0.42 -1.73 -1.63
#2: 2015-08-14 00:30:00  0.87 -0.32  0.54  0.15  0.56 -0.21 -0.94  0.78  0.01 -0.22  0.64 -0.16
#3: 2015-08-14 03:30:00  0.57  0.18 -0.15 -0.11  0.03  0.01  0.19  0.06 -0.24  0.06 -0.02  0.15
#4: 2015-08-14 06:30:00  0.44 -0.78  0.37 -0.05  0.04 -0.15 -0.24 -0.17  0.19  0.03  0.05 -0.37
```

Comment: What are data_ch1[-1,1] and data_ch1[-1] doing here? Thanks.

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang  `data_chi[-1]` (assuming that the `data_chi` is `data.frame`), will remove the first column, `data_chi[-1,1]`, subsets the first column without the first row.  I just updated with a data.table method as I didn't notice earlier that you were using `data.table`.  Also, the first method should work if you convert to `data.frame`, ie. `setDF(data_chi)` or we have to use `data_chi[,-1, with=FALSE]` for subsetting.

Comment: can you guide me how to loop through data_chi in your example?

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang  I added some more description.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I got the error message: > dfrm <- data.table(lapply(data_ch1[-1], function(x) {
+     x1 <- diff(x)
+     ifelse(x1 <=-5|x1 >=5, NA, x1)}))
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang  As I said earlier, have you  converted `data_chi` to `data.frame` while working with the first method i.e. `lapply(setDF(data_chi)[-1], function(x) ...`

Comment: how to move the timestamp to the 1st column in your example?

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang  In the updated version `DT <- data_chi[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {x1 <- diff(x)
            NA^(x1 <= -5 | x1 >=5)*x1}), .SDcols= 2:ncol(data_chi)
           ][, timestamp := data_chi[[1]][-1]]; DT1 <- DT[, c(ncol(DT), 1:(ncol(DT)-1)), with=FALSE]`

Comment: only this part works: DT <- data_ch1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {x1 <- diff(x)
NA^(x1 <= -5 | x1 >=5)*x1}), .SDcols= 2:ncol(data_ch1)]

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang  I don't get any errors while working with the example you provided.